# Error con el Gradle de Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Llevo unos días desde que instalé la *versión 2.3* de *Android Studio* que no me compilan lo proyectos por el *Gradle*, lo he reinstalado varias veces, incluso borrado las carpetas ocultas con un `.` delante, pero todo sigue igual.

> Error, fallo al resolver (`\Prueba\app\build.gradle`):
>
> ```
> junit:junit:4.12
> javax.inject:javax.inject:1
> javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
> com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
> org.hamcret:hamcrest-library:1.3
> org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
> com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
> ```

Código del **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jonathan.prueba"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Código del build.gradle del proyecto:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Imagen Actual del Proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has intentado quitar la linea `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`?? y `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })`

Comment: Si he intentado quitarlas y cualquier dependecia que intento añadir me sale lo mismo.

Comment: No es linux es Windows. Al quitarlas parece que si compila pero no me deja incluir otras dependecias. Intento por ejemplo añadir esta compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0' y me sale lo mismo Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0
<a href="openFile:C:/Prueba/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: y intentaste donde está `repositories {
        jcenter()
    }`agregar tambien `mavenCentral()` o agregar la ultima linea de este archivo a tu graddle https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/blob/master/circleimageview/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Lo que muestra el error:

```
Error, fallo al resolver (\Prueba\app\build.gradle):
junit:junit:4.12
javax.inject:javax.inject:1
javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
org.hamcret:hamcrest-library:1.3
org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
```

no coincide con lo que muestras en tu archivo `app\build.gradle`, simplemente realiza una limpieza de los archivos del proyecto: `Build` > `Clean Project`

y sincroniza el proyecto con los archivos `build.gradle`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al hacer el clean proyect recibo un error Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/hdodenhof/circleimageview/2.1.0/circleimageview-2.1.0.pom'............................................................... No me deja adjuntar el error entero

Comment: agrega tu settings.gradle

Comment: Solo tiene la linea de include ':app', debe ser el graddle porque en la ventana de event logs me sale Gradle sync failed: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip'.

Comment: Me parece que tienes registrados otros módulos, selecciona el proyecto y con botón derecho abre "Open Module settings" o F4 si pudieras agregar una imagen.

Comment: http://subefotos.com/ver/?a8aa4fbf05221c7c7ac29a3954d8b467o.png

Comment: no se ve, puedes agregarla a pregunta creo que es más fácil

Comment: @JonathanPescador veo la imagen, esto es un poco raro, te propongo algo elimina los 2 folder /build, el de la raiz de tu proyect y el /build dentro de /app, después construye nuevamente el proyecto.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado y nada.Ya no se que más probar

Comment: Es un poco extraño, busca en tu proyecto por texto donde tienes definido algo de esto: junit:junit:4.12
javax.inject:javax.inject:1
javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
org.hamcret:hamcrest-library:1.3
org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1

Comment: He quitado todas dependecias menos la de appcombat y me funciona el problema es que no puedo añadir niguna dependecia externa

Comment: Gente, las aclaraciones se piden como comentarios a la pregunta y los datos adicoinales se ponen EN la pregunta, editándola.